# Update SESSION variables when form is submitted

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form in account.php that is prefilled with the user's current info but can be changed and then when you submit, it updates the database. However, when returned to the page after the update, the prefilled text is not updated. It only updates if you re-log in. At this point I have only messed with updating the username.

Comment: It's because you have to update the session variable too, after updating the values in the database.

Comment: How to update the session variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An little example for updating a session var. I hope this helps:

```
<?php
session_start();

// database update or whatever

$_SESSION['username'] = $newUserName;

//Something else

?>
```